# How can I find text between frame brackets with php regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have this php:

```
preg_match_all("/\[\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]\]/", $html, $mm);
                          foreach($mm as $m)
                {      
                    $i++;
                    $v=$i."-".time()."-".rand();
                    $vars["".$v.""]=$m[0];
                    $html=str_replace($m[0], "".$v."", $html);
                }
```

I have some text in my html like [[[SOMETHING]]]. I use them as markers. But now I whould like to get them all and replace with a number... (for a while) My regex don't do the job. What's the wrong with this regex?

Comment: Just use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead of a loop.

Comment: It is a little hard to glean intent without example _input/output_. It looks like you are replacing, with that str_replace() from the beginning to end of the string each time in your loop. Probably not what you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of what you are looking for: `\[\[\[(.*?)\]\]\]`. This will find anything between 3 brackets like in your example. If you want to change the characters that you are searching between just change the brackets to something else.